# To show that a sequence of functions is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove:

Show that 
$$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^{2/3}}$$ is Cauchy in $L^1[0,2\pi]$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Have you considered that $f_n$ converges to the Fourier series of some function?

Comment: @MichaelLee It converges to $\operatorname S_{2/3}(x)$, a Clausen function.  Not sure how that helps much though :P

Comment: That's fine. As long as $S_{2/3}(x)$ is square-integrable on $[0, 2\pi]$, we know that $f_n\to S_{2/3}$ in $L^2$ (by [Riesz-Fischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem)), and as $[0, 2\pi]$ is finite, this would imply $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: Ah, okay, that should do it then @MichaelLee

Comment: @MichaelLee That's the clear and easy approach, and you should include it as an answer.

Comment: @zhw. Done. Let me know if you think it needs any more details.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: overkill. The functions $g_k(x)=\frac{\sin(k x)}{k}$ are symmetric with respect to $x=\pi$, hence it is enough to prove that $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is convergent in $ L^1\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. By the Fejer-Jackson inequality
$$ \forall x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right),\forall n\geq 1,\qquad G_n(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{n}g_k(x) \geq 0 \tag{1}$$
and by summation by parts
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/3}g_k(x) = n^{1/3} G_n(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}G_k(x)\left((k+1)^{1/3}-k^{1/3}\right).\tag{2}$$
On the other hand
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}G_m(x)\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{\pi k}{4}}{k^2} \tag{3}$$
converges to a finite limit ($\frac{3\pi^2}{16}$) as $m\to +\infty$, as fast as $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}G_m(x)\,dx = \frac{3\pi^2}{16}-O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)$,  and $(k+1)^{1/3}-k^{1/3}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{3k^{2/3}}$ for large values of $k$. Long story short: we may prove the convergence in $L^1$ like we prove the pointwise convergence, since the Fejer-Jackson inequality provides a non-negative bound that is simple and effective to exploit by summation by parts.

Answer (score 1):

We first admit the following lemma:

> For $\{c_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, the function $f : [0, 2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x) := \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} c_k\sin(kx)$$ is in $L^2([0, 2\pi])$.

Namely, the partial sums are Cauchy in $L^2([0, 2\pi])$, as $$\left\|\sum_{k=M}^N c_k\sin(kx)\right\|_{L^2([0, 2\pi])}^2 = \pi\sum_{k=M}^N c_k^2$$ due to the orthogonality of $\{\sin(kx)\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $L^2([0, 2\pi])$ and the fact that $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x = \pi$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. We let $c_k = \frac{1}{k^{2/3}}$ for $k\geq 1$ (and $c_k = 0$ otherwise) and note that $$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} c_k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{4/3}} = \zeta(4/3)\approx 3.6$$ Therefore, $f(x) := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^{2/3}}$ is in $L^2([0, 2\pi])$. The [Riesz-Fischer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem) then tells us that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2([0, 2\pi])$. As $[0, 2\pi]$ has finite measure, we have the inclusion $L^2([0, 2\pi])\subset L^1([0, 2\pi])$, so $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1([0, 2\pi])$. This implies that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy in $L^1([0, 2\pi])$.

More generally, this works for any series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^z}$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^z}$ with $z > 1/2$ (i.e. such that $\zeta(2z)$ is finite).

Comment: This is fine, but actually I'd include fewer details. It's just a matter of the orthogonality of the functions $\sin kx.$ Thus for large $M\le N,$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} |\sum_{k=M}^{N} c_k\sin (kx)|^2\, dx = \pi\sum_{k=M}^{N} c_k^2<\epsilon$$

given $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k^2<\infty.$

Comment: Edited. Thanks!

Comment: No, you need orthogonality.

Comment: You're right. The triangle inequality only works if $\{c_k\}$ is in $\ell^1$. Edited again.